# 2 belongs_to, 1 has_many : Team/Game relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

I have two models Game and Team:

```
    class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :home_team, class_name: 'Team', required: true
      belongs_to :visitor_team, class_name: 'Team', required: true
    end
```

and

```
    class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :games
    end
```

The relationship has_many  :games doesn't work (I would have to specify class_name but in this case I have two class names). I have to differentiate home and visitor.

Any idea on how to design this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the `foreign_key`, assuming you have columns `home_team_id` and `visitor_team_id` in `games` table:

```
has_many :home_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: :home_team_id
has_many :visitor_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: :visitor_team_id
```

Comment: This is wrong. It has nothing to do with the declaration of `belongs_to`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. However the foreign_key doesn't change anything here. I'm still getting "SQLException: no such column: games.team_id". I think the issue is probably in the declaration of has_many but I don't know what's missing.

Comment: Sorry, copied the wrong lines to edit... I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`has_many` will look for a foreign key with the same name as the class you're working in.

In this case, Rails will assume there is a `team_id` in the associated `Game` class, linking back to the Team.This isn't the case, so you need to be more explicit.

In this case, you also don't have a single link from a Game back to a Team. There are two different links between Game and Team, so you need to represent both of these links as associations:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :home_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: :home_team_id
  has_many :visitor_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: :visitor_team_id
end
```

If you want to get all games for a given team, regardless of whether they are home or visitng games, you can define a method:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :home_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: :home_team_id
  has_many :visitor_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: :visitor_team_id

  def games
    Game.where('home_team_id = ? or visitor_team_id = ?', id, id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! :)

That's exactly what I currently have but I was hoping to replace my "games" method by a pretty has_many.